# Details of the Makara Vyuha

Tags: mahabharata, history, vyuha

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurukshetra_War#Military_Formations) article mentions a list of battle formations used in the *Mahabharata*. Amongst other formations, *Makara Vyuha* is mentioned. I would like to know if the details of this Vyuha are mentioned in the Mahabharata. Is so, what is this formation?

Comment: I think Makara Vyuha is arranging group of army in the form of crocodile and attacking from front or mouth part like crocodile (Makara)...

Comment: Instead of posting one by one why don't you post a single question like "How does each Vyasa function?" Or do you want a very detailed explanation for it? Because for most Vyuhas I guess only their names and the implied meanings will be mentioned.

Comment: @Surya: That is what I did in the other question 'What are different battle strategies and battle formations?'. It was put on hold as too broad.